# TcpClient on Windows Mobile 6.5 device unable to communicate when docked

Tags: winforms

I have C# application running on dot net compact framework 3.5 on a Windows mobile 6.5 device which utilises TcpClient and NetworkStream to send a byte array to a service running on the host PC. It must be able to communicate by docking the device in a cradle and connecting via Windows Mobile Device Centre, which is set to allow data connections on the device when connected to PC. 
I am getting the following error 'Unable to read data from the transport connection'. It works perfectly well when the same device is connected to the network via wifi, but this is not an option as there is no wifi where it will be deployed. It is the nwStream.Write line in the code snippet below where the error occurs:

```
public bool PostInitialData(string ipAddress, int portNo, string dataString)
    {
        bool retVal = true;

        try
        {
            IPAddress stringIPAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddress);

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
            tcpClient.Connect(stringIPAddress, portNo);

            NetworkStream nwStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] bytesToSend = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dataString);

            //---send the text

            nwStream.Write(bytesToSend, 0, bytesToSend.Length);

            //---read back the text

            byte[] bytesToRead = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            int numBytesRead = nwStream.Read(bytesToRead, 0, tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
            string serverResponse = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesToRead, 0, numBytesRead);


            tcpClient.Close();

            if (serverResponse != "OK")
            {
                retVal = false;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError.ErrorHandler.LogErrorDetail(ex);
            retVal = false;
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to make a virtual network adapter to acomplish the connectivity of the two devices.

Comment: The device is connecting, I can access the internet and update networked SQL server instances with the device in the dock.

Comment: Question : Can you ping your server IP from the PDA?